# What is a bhashya? What rules are there to write bhashya?

Tags: scripture, commentary

What is bhashya (commentary)? What is the method for writing bhashyas? Which scripture tells us about bhashya? Do Puranas talk about bhashyas?

Comment: It started with brahma sutra, gita and upanishad.. here Advaita says 1 brahma all are illusion. to support this view that is what brahma sutr, gita and upanishand and veda was taking about they need their way of interperatation.. otherwise there are dualist statement in all the brahma sutra, gita, upanishad and veda.. which cannot be interreperted otherwise without bhasya, the followers of one particualr philosophy is confused.

Comment: Hello did not talk about any Vedanta . I am asking what is bhashya and Do puranas tells about bhashya

Comment: what do mean by vedanta it is veda siddantha (i.e. Upanishad and Vedas) combined. Puranas, Brahma sutras, Gita are written by Lord Veda Vyasa before Bhasya kara created their Bhasyas

Comment: I question is on bhashya not on vedanta

Comment: I would recommend you to check this out https://www.academia.edu/2160162/Sanskrit_Philosophical_Commentary_2010_
Here, the author has explained bhāṣya in an extremely detailed and lucid manner, quoting from śāstras and example bhāṣyas too. I don't know any other work, which explains various types of commentaries in such a proper manner.